# Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA (No manual transaction statements)

Tags: java, glassfish, entity, derby

I understand this query has been dealt with in other discussions, but I have not mixed @Transactional with a em.getTranstaction.begin() or any other manual transaction statement. (Using glassfish and netbeans 8)

Code below:

MainDao

```html
package com.restaurant.orders;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
public class MainDao {
    
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;
    
    @Transactional
    public void addUser(Users user) {
        em.persist(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addOrder(Orders order) {
        em.persist(order);
    }
    
    @Transactional
    public void addOrderItem(Orderitems orderitem) {
        em.persist(orderitem);
    }
    
    public List<Users> getAllUsers() {
    TypedQuery<Users> query = em.createQuery(
        "SELECT g FROM Users g ORDER BY g.id", Users.class);
    return query.getResultList();
    }
    
    public List<Orders> getAllOrders() {
    TypedQuery<Orders> query = em.createQuery(
        "SELECT g FROM Orders g ORDER BY g.id", Orders.class);
    return query.getResultList();
    }
    
    public List<Orderitems> getAllOrderItems() {
    TypedQuery<Orderitems> query = em.createQuery(
        "SELECT g FROM Orderitems g ORDER BY g.id", Orderitems.class);
    return query.getResultList();
    }
    
}
```

persistence.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com.restaurant_restaurant_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>orders</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.restaurant.orders.Users</class>
    <class>com.restaurant.orders.Orderitems</class>
    <class>com.restaurant.orders.Orders</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
 
  <!-- Use @Component annotations for bean definitions -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.restaurant.orders"/>
 
  <!-- Use @Controller annotations for MVC controller definitions -->
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
 

  <!-- Add JPA support -->
  <bean id="emf" class=
       "org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
     <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class=
 "org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
      </property>
  </bean>
 
  <!-- Add Transaction support -->
  <bean id="myTxManager"
     class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
  </bean>
 
  <!-- Use @Transaction annotations for managing transactions -->
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTxManager" />
 
  <!-- View resolver -->
 <bean class=
     "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
 </bean>
 
</beans>
```

Trace:

```html
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA.
root cause

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA.
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA.
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

add metadata-complete="true" to your web.xml like that

```html
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         metadata-complete="true">
```